# Looking for a horizontal treeview in jQuery

Tags: jquery, treeview

Is there a treeview control out there that is horizontally aligned like an org chart?

Treeview control is normally vertically aligned. Or is such a control called something else and not treeview?

Comment: Could you download it? It seems its quite difficult to get to the download link.

Comment: @FabianLauer, please learn some manners. This is a site for professionals. Even if a question is flawed. there is no need whatsoever to reply in that way. It helps literally no one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a jQuery control for a horizontal tree view. Actually, its more appropriately called `org chart`. Here is the link that I found having a free org chart for use with jQuery.

1. https://github.com/caprica/jquery-orgchart